# How to add javascript event handler to DevExpress MVC combobox?

Tags: javascript, devexpress-mvc

I inherited a project that makes use of DevExpress controls in a Microsoft VS MVC project. I am used to writing javascript, so added an event handler and used jQuery to attach it to a DevExpress combobox control.

But it doesn't handle the event. I used Chrome's inspection tool on the control, which revealed that DevExpress spawned a compound control whose ID was the design-time ID with a "_I" added. So I used the modified ID as the ID of the control to which I wanted to add the event handler.

Still no luck. I put a break point on the handler in Chrome's sources tab, and the breakpoint is never reached.

I have searched all over the DevExpress site and not found an explanation of how to handle  this most commonplace of tasks.

What do I do?

Comment: Hi Scott, do you need to add the event handler dynamically via JS? The general way to handle this would be to configure it on the View containing the ComboBox with something like s.Properties.ClientSideEvents.ValueChanged = "comboBox_ValueChanged". That would point to a comboBox_ValueChanged JS method to handle the event.

Answer (score 0):

Gary is correct. I need to add ClientSideEvents language. A lot of trouble for something that should be quite easy. [enter link description here](https://documentation.devexpress.com/AspNet/9448/Common-Concepts/Client-Side-Functionality/Client-Side-Events)